# Making an interface with reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very noob with reactJs, in fact I just finished [this course](https://www.udemy.com/complete-react-js-course/) and am struggling with some concepts here.

I am willing to create an app for people to express their preferences with regards of subjects for a newsletter, and have grabbed a very comprehensive list of topics (2k+) and wanna make some fun way to select them, so I think that something along the lines of Tinder swipeable cards would be a perfect fit, so I am trying to implement [this react module](https://alexandre-garrec.github.io/react-swipe-card/?selectedKind=Tinder%20card&selectedStory=all%20swipe%20directions&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=kadirahq%2Fstorybook-addon-actions%2Factions-panel) functionality into my App.

But it is not showing up anything.

I just [created a Repo](https://gitlab.com/rafareino/swipe-problem-example), in which I had a few tries with no luck.

Basically, the example provided in the module documentation says that it should start by

```
const data = ['Alexandre', 'Thomas', 'Lucien', 'Raphael', 'Donatello', 'Michelangelo', 'Leonardo']


const Wrapper = () => {
  return (
      <Cards onEnd={console.log("action('end')")} className='master-root'>
        {data.map(item => 
          <Card 
            onSwipeLeft={console.log("action('swipe left')")} 
            onSwipeRight={console.log("action('swipe right')")}>
            <h2>{item}</h2>
          </Card>
        )}
      </Cards>
  )
}
```

But I am completely lost with it, I supposed that it should provide me with a React Component `<Something />`, but instead it generate something in the lines of a function, that returns a `div`, which looks a lot with a component, but I have no idea about how integrate into this example.

---

Note: In the repo graph, I noticed that there is another [developer](https://github.com/yellowiscool/react-swipe-card#code) that made some adjustments to make it compatible with react 16.xx.beta, I'v tried it also, no lucky also.

I am almost sure, that there are some concepts I am missing here, so, any reference is more than welcome, also.

Comment: Can you show more code? Did you install the module with `npm install`? Are you importing the necessary swipe card files in your React components?

Comment: Oh, please, forgive me for this enormous mistake! I did created a repo, but forgot to link it in the question... Here it go https://gitlab.com/rafareino/swipe-problem-example

Comment: _By the way_ I installed the module with `npm install react-swipe-card -S` and included (https://gitlab.com/rafareino/swipe-problem-example/blob/master/src/myCards.js#L2) the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your app, and noticed that the `react-swipe-card` module is not present in your `package.json` file, so running `npm install` actually doesn't install it.

If you run the below command, it will install the `react-swipe-card` module, and automatically add it to your `package.json` file.

`npm install react-swipe-card --save`

The `--save` switch saves it to the `dependencies` section of your `package.json` file.

Comment: In fact, but this didn't solve the problem. To be clear, I tried a few times before became able to completely describe and isolate the issue.